# Did any other characters have pieces of Vorlons inside them?

Tags: babylon-5

John Sheridan carried a piece of Kosh inside him during several episodes. You could say Kosh was hidden in Sheridan.

Lyta Alexander carried Ulkesh inside her.

Did Vorlons hide inside anybody else besides John Sheridan and Lyta Alexander?

Answer (score 7):

This is going to be another boring answer... but **no character or storyline ever suggests this happens again,** at least during the time of the main plot.

Kosh and Ulkesh are the only two Vorlon that are ever seen interfacing with any of the younger races.  Their earliest plotline appearance is *In The Beginning*, and there's no trace of any essence sharing having been done there (they do cameo in an earlier time in *War Without End*, but that's all they do).  Kosh's presence is mostly on Babylon 5, and Ulkesh's is mostly offscreen with the Rangers up until he also moves to Babylon 5.  There are some additional glimpses of them in some of the novels - Sinclair is introduced to Ulkesh when he begins leading the Rangers, and Kosh is shown monitoring the techno-mage situation from time to time.  Neither shows any signs of finding a host for them.

There is a scene which depicts Kosh's death from his own point of view, and in between other thoughts, there's this...

> If his aide were nearby, he could pour the core of his essence into her, as he sometimes did. She had been modified and trained to carry him, concealed inside her, when he required it. No other on the station had the strength to carry even a small portion of his core. If she were here, though, the enemy would have first sought her out and killed her, to prevent any such transfer. Kosh was glad he had sent her away. - *Invoking Darkness*, Chapter 1

The context of his hiding in Sheridan is that of a moment of desperation - the Shadows were literally tearing him apart, and afraid to die, he seized on a piece and plunged it into Sheridan through their link. Even though that shouldn't have worked (either Kosh should have dissipated or Sheridan should have burned out), the piece was small enough and their bond just strong enough for it to happen.

So it doesn't happen in front of us.  @Dranon's answer suggests they have shared essence in the past with other agents to keep tabs on the younger races.  It looks like without prep - or desperate luck - it doesn't happen easily, and we see no one else in the storyline (save perhaps Sebastian) that strongly connected to the Vorlon.

Comment: According to Lorien, this is something that they can do. Lyta's modifications and training made it easier for Kosh and Ulkesh, but I don't think that it's otherwise impossible.

Comment: @Radhil I think the earliest chronological appearance of Kosh and Ulkesh is when they were on Babylon-4 over 1000 years earlier.

Comment: @RichS - I hadn't realized those were the same two Vorlon, but it's moot; there's no information we can extract from a 5 second appearance isolated by 1000 years.

Comment: @Dranon - if it were that easy, they'd never have to die, they'd just keep dumping their core into hosts endlessly.  Kosh might not do that, cause morals, but Ulkesh would.  It's very likely they've done this with other people, keeping tabs on the races over the centuries, but I just don't see any other possibilities for hosting a Vorlon within the characters and plots we see.  And I still think it'd be a rare thing regardless, the way they act so completely above their lesser.

Comment: In the end, we both agree with the main point: we never see it done to anyone else within the context of the show. If you were to soften your answer to say that it is something they can do, but it appears to usually take prep work, and it might not be all that common, I think it would be a better answer.

Comment: @Dranon - eh, ok, done, and have an upvote.

Comment: Thanks. Upvote for you as well. I think this is now the better of our two answers.

Answer (score 1):

Within the show it's not shown that they hide or ride around inside anyone else, but it is something that they can do. As Lorien says in "Whatever Happened to Mr. Garibaldi":

> They can break off pieces of their consciousness and put it into other organisms. It allows them to travel hidden through the galaxy, using others as their eyes and ears.